# I have a problem with running the mkdocs serve command

Tags: python, pip, mkdocs

I tried running the `mkdocs serve` command on the windows command prompt but it wasn't working. I get the following error:

```
INFO    -  Building documentation...
ERROR   -  Config value: 'markdown_extensions'. Error: Failed loading extension "mdx_math".
```

Aborted with 1 Configuration Errors!

I then noticed that my terminal directory wasn't on the `mkdocs.yml` file as stated in the [MkDocs Website](https://www.mkdocs.org/#getting-started) but when I ran `cd` command to change the directory to the `mkdocs.yml`, I got the following error:

```
The directory name is invalid.
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your extension isn't installed.

Try:  `pip install mdx_math`

Answer (score 0):

Please install the missing extensions by

```
pip install python-markdown-math
```